# Best smart glasses for heads-up display of text?

Tags: displays

I am looking for AR smart glasses focused on heads-up display, such as that provided by [ActiveLook](https://www.activelook.net/pages/for-consumers). I would like to see in my field of vision short snippets of text, such as a grocery list, and easily scroll through them.

- Products sold by **Vuzix** would do the trick I'm sure but they are extremely expensive, probably due to the cameras, mics and plenty of other elements without which I can do.
- **XREAL** glasses immerse you in movies or games; I would need a device that can be worn while walking around.
- As for controlling the display, I liked the idea of the ring on the **North Focals**